# Error: std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, linux

Estoy teniendo este problema, el programa compila y linkea, pero a la hora de ejecutar me tira este fallo, si alguien me pudiera dar una mano.

> ~/Projects/Queue using vector# ./main terminate called
>   after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'   what(): 
>   vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 18446744073709551615) >=
>   this->size() (which is 20) Abortado

Comment: sin codigo será dificil que recibas ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlo:

> ~/Projects/Queue using vector# ./main se llamó a terminate tras lanzar una instancia de 'std::out_of_range'

La función [`std::terminate`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) se llama automáticamente cuando una excepción es lanzada (*thrown*) pero no es recogida (*catch*).

La excepción que se te ha lanzado es [`std::out_of_range`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) que traducido sería "Fuera de rango", esta función se lanza (entre otros motivos) cuando se intenta acceder a una zona de memoria presuntamente manejada por un contenedor sin que la zona de memoria solicitada pertenezca a dicho contenedor.

Eso es exáctamente lo que te ha pasado, el error indica que estás usando un `std::vector` y seguramente has llamado a la función [`std::vector::at`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) la cual puede lanzar la excepción mencionada. El error te indica que has accedido a la posición dieciocho trillones cuatrocientos cuarenta y seis mil setecientos cuarenta y cuatro billones setenta y tres mil setecientos nueve millones quinientos cincuenta y un mil seiscientos quincésima, que es la posición 2<sup>64</sup>.

Apuesto a que has pasado un número negativo a la función `std::vector::at` y como el parámetro es de tipo entero sin signo (generalmente [`std::size_t`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)) ha desbordado.